# How to install Homebrew in specified folder ? For example , in the Home directory

Tags: java, homebrew

I have installed Homebrew via the Terminal with help of this line of code `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` on my Mac Os and it has been downloaded to `/usr/local` folder.

How can I install it to specified folder for example my Home Folder `/Users/Petrov`?

Answer (score 3):

The needed steps are described on the [official homepage](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere)

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
```

then

```
eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
brew update --force --quiet
chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"
```